# Sidekiq Job Fails in Production | NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have an `Expenditure` model:

```
class Expenditure < ApplicationRecord
  multi_tenant :company
  after_commit :related_reindex

  def related_reindex
    ExpenditureRelatedReindex.perform_async(id)
  end
end
```

Here is my worker `expenditure_related_reindex.rb`:

```
class ExpenditureRelatedReindex
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :queue => :critical, :retry => true, :backtrace => true

  def perform(record_id)
    e = Expenditure.find(record_id)

    MultiTenant.with(e.company) do
      return unless e
      e.expenditure_items.each(&:reindex)
      e.children&.each(&:reindex)
    end
  end
end
```

The reindex can take some time so I want these to spin off to SideKiq.  I have sime multi tenant code I should mention but I don't think it's the issue.  After the record is updated I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ExpenditureRelatedReindex
Did you mean?  ExpenditureItemsHelper
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:268:in `const_get'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:268:in `constantize'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/rails.rb:43:in `block in call'
  from active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
  from active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
  from active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
  from active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
  from sidekiq/rails.rb:42:in `call'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:257:in `stats'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/job_logger.rb:13:in `call'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/job_retry.rb:78:in `global'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:124:in `block in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/logger.rb:10:in `with'
  from sidekiq/job_logger.rb:33:in `prepare'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:123:in `dispatch'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:162:in `process'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:78:in `process_one'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
  from sidekiq/util.rb:15:in `watchdog'
  from sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
```

I have even taken out the entire 'perform' block of code i.e. the worker does nothing to confirm I don't have some sort of  regressive call etc.  I confirm that my other workers fire and process just fine.  Checked for obvious typos - banging my head against the wall at this point.

**UPDATE**

Ok - I have confirmed one thing - if I add any new workers with any name this triggers the same error.  I even rebooted the entire production server to confirm the whole code was reloaded etc.

Comment: Sorry for the turn-it-off-and-on-again question, but if this is a new job have you restarted sidekiq? Sidekiq only loads classes once at startup, so you have to cycle it when pushing a new job.

Comment: I just checked the dashboard and the process shows the same start time as my past deploy.  Tried to even rename the Worker to see if it was some weird plural name.

Comment: Hmmm.. that might have been the issue after all.  In the dashboard I STOPPED the process and then re-deployed.  All seems to work now.  I need to add this to my deploy script some how.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being Redis (or at least my fix was related).  Found this post:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2834#issuecomment-184800981

and it was a Redis namespace conflict.  My server does have elasticsearch running also so that makes sense.  I am not sure why the old workers run but the new ones failed.  My fix looks like this:

```
config.redis = {
    url: ENV['REDIS_URL'],
    namespace: "some_namespace_different_for_each_app"
  }
```

You also need the `redis-namespace` gem BTW